# Maven Not Copying Dependencies to WEB-INF/lib in Eclipse

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, jakarta-ee, classpath

I realize anywhere from very similar to identical questions have been asked numerous times on StackOverflow, but most if not all seem to end up having different solutions.

I have tried almost everything that I have found from similar questions posted here and elsewhere, yet I still can't get Maven to put the dependency JARs in WEB-INF/lib.

The oddest thing is that every time I run Maven -> Update Project, Maven seems to reconfigure the class output folder to be `/target/classes` instead of `/war/WEB-INF/classes` which is required by the Google web app plugin.

Everything shows up correctly under Maven Dependencies in the build path, but nothing shows up in WEB-INF/lib, so the app fails with ClassNotFoundExceptions at runtime.

Here is the relevant part of the pom.xml:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>war/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Is there something I have to configure in the M2E settings? Do I need to use a maven terminal command? I am really at a loss for what to do other than manually manage all dependencies (please... no).

Comment: It does not look like you have followed the directions at [Importing a Maven Project](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse#Importing_a_Maven_Project) because you have not specified the appengine-maven-plugin configuration.

Comment: I must have missed that. I added it under <plugins>, but it did not solve the problem. Maven -> Update Project also still reverts back to using /target/classes for some reason.

Comment: Your project might be not correctly set for maven. Check if in your web project - `Properties > Deployment Assembly` you have Maven Dependencies set to be deployed to `WEB-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<build>
    <outputDirectory>war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
</build>
```

Add that to your pom. It will stop the output directory changing everytime you do a Maven Update.

Comment: This question is kind of old now, but I'm pretty sure this is the right solution, iirc.